# NSDictionary returns null value after parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xml-parsing

I am doing XMLParsing for my app. To get the parsed value in dictionary i have used `XMLReader.h` and `XMLReader.m` file. It works for all web services but returns `null`. It gives me correct response in XML format.

Here is the code where I get the values in dictionary

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if(elementFound)
    {
        [soapResults appendString:string];
        NSLog(@"soap result of hotel  is %@",soapResults);
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        NSDictionary *xmlDixtionary =  [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:soapResults error:&parseError];

        NSLog(@"dictionary is  is %@",xmlDixtionary);
    }

}
```

But the log gives me a `null` value , what should I do to get the values in dictionary?

Comment: Try to log parseError: NSLog(@"%@", parseError);

Comment: it gives me this error Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)"

Comment: Does soapResults has some value? Try nslogging it also..

Comment: NSMutableDictionary * xmlDixtionary =  (NSMutableDictionary*])[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:soapResults error:&parseError];

Comment: And can you show us an excerpt of the `soapResults` logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Something for you : [XML Parsing - NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486116/xml-parsing-nsxmlparsererrordomain-error-5)

It shows the possibility of problem in encoding.

One more link : [[iPhone] Can not parse simple XML](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1924078?start=0&tstart=0)

Hope It will be useful for you.

Comment: i am not using any xml file instead i am getting the esponse in xml format, btw thanks.

Answer (score 1):

soapResults isn't the full string that you are searching for, you have just append a piece of string to it.You need to keep appending characters and to create the dictionary only at the end of the element.

Implement this method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;
```